# IBM Worklight 6.0 - "Error: Unable to read repository at http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl..."

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to add IBM Worklight plugin to my eclipse environment in Mac 10.7.5 system. I am using Eclipse version Juno 4.2.2 (SR2) for Java EE developers, and using JAVA 7. I tried to install worklight plugin through "Eclipse marketplace" and through "Install new software" using IBM URL.

In both cases i am getting below error after installation progress is at "44%".

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/wdeupdate/plugins/com.ibm.imp.webtools.dojo.library.distributions_2.0.0.v20130508_1207.jar.
Connection reset
Unable to read repository at http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/wdeupdate/plugins/com.worklight.studio.plugin_6.0.0.20130614-0631.jar.
Connection reset
```

[image]

Let me know if I am missing anything while adding plugin. I was able to add worklight to my eclipse in Windows 7 system. But in Mac system I am facing problems.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this question resolved? Please mark as Answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved, slow network connection was the issue for me. Using a good speed net connection I was able to Install the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

See this topic: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/270718/

Try starting Eclipse with `-vmargs -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`.

Answer (score 1):

In my situation I had to right-click on eclipse.exe and Run as Administrator and the problem went away.